# Trying to attach multiple inputs to a forloop to ultimately return multiple outputs (python)

Tags: python, for-loop, input

I am trying to create a program that asks for twenty two inputs and then calculates forty four outputs (inputs are put through two different calculations) and return those forty four outputs.

I have ran into trouble trying to connect asking for the multiple inputs into returning the outputs. I have been able to return forty four outputs with this code:

```
def forloop():
    for i in range(22):
        print("The area of the circle is: ", i * radius**2)
        print("The circumference of the circle is: ", 2*pi*radius)`
```

However, I have not figured out how to ask the user for the twenty two inputs and relate those to the for-loop I have created.

Answer (score 0):

You want to learn how to [read input](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/taking-input-in-python/) from the terminal in python. This is how you can do it.

```
def forloop():
    for i in range(22):
        data = input("Enter a number: ")
        # Do the computation you want to do on this input
        print("The area of the circle is: ", i * radius**2)
        print("The circumference of the circle is: ", 2*pi*radius)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 lists. One for input, one for radius, and one for circumference:

```
input_list = []
radius_list = []
circumference_list = []

for i in range(22)
   input= input("Enter a number: ")
   input_list.append(input)
   radius_list.append(input * radius**2)
   circumference_list.append(2*pi*radius)
```